# AJAX & PHP: load foreign domain via proxy and use session cookie?

Tags: php, ajax, load

i wonder if i'm doing anything wrong or I am just getting this wrong?

I'm loading a part of a of subdomain with jquery load(). just before i'm firing the load method i'm saving a password to a $_SESSION with php. The part of the subdomain i'm loading with jquery load() needs this password information.

Does this count as the same session, because I can't retrieve the $_SESSION information inside my loaded subdomain part?

Or isn't this working because I'm actually loading a part of DIFFERENT website so the session is a different one?

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is tied to a cookie named `PHPSESSID`, which is by default available only to the *exact* domain name where you use it. `a.example.com` can't access cookies from `b.example.com`, and so the sessions can't cross over, either.

There is, however, a way to set the `PHPSESSID` cookie to be available across your entire domain: [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params) allows you to apply relevant settings to that `PHPSESSID` cookie. By setting the domain to `.example.com` (the dot at the front must be there!), you make the cookie available to `example.com` and all subdomains.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
```

Comment: where do i have to set that? just right after the session_start(); ?

Comment: @mathiregister - I've never used it; I only found it in the PHP docs by Googling. I'd bet you would put it *before* `session_start`, so that the session starts with the correct settings. Some browsers and extensions will allow you to inspect your cookies in detail - that might help for debugging this particular bit.

Comment: do happen to know if session_set_cookie_params() also works for the set_cookie() method? or do i have to use sessions?

Comment: @mathiregister - [see the manual page on setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie) - if you want those options, use the optional arguments on `setcookie`.